# Session becomes null after browser is closed

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I use the following code to retrieve login user identity across pages

```
// login method of account model
public ActionResult Login(LoginModel model)
{
    Session["username"]=model.Username;
    //redirect to login controler
}
```

and in login controler

```
public ActionResult LoginLayout()
{
    if(IsAdmin(Session["username"]))
        return View();
    else
        return OtherView();
}
```

Everything is fine until I close the browser then reopen it, I am always then redirected to `OtherView()` even if I am still authenticated as login user.

**Update**

```
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Login(LoginModel model, string returnUrl)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid && WebSecurity.Login(model.UserName, model.Password, persistCookie: model.RememberMe))
        {                
            Session["username"] = model.UserName;
            return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
        }

        // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        ModelState.AddModelError("", "The user name or password provided is incorrect.");
        return View(model);
    }
```

Comment: What makes you say you are "still authenticated"?

Comment: Well I mean I am still being logged on as a login user

Comment: to expand on what Floris asked, did you choose an authentication method (like cookies) that persists past Session? If so, please be specific and include code.

Comment: How can you tell? What does "still logged in" mean? Usually when you close the browser you are automatically logged out - what is different here?

Comment: @DaveA Yes, LogIn Method of Websecurity I use the persistent cookies and I also choose Remember Me provided by Firefox

Comment: Please add you login method to your post. BTW, remember me is not 'remain logged in'. it's remember my username. But cookies are legit. Though their setting is the first place I would check for errors. The second is your security filters.

Comment: Ok, but that's a start. how do you assure you're using cookies? It looks like you're just using Session. Are you using a custom auth filter?

Comment: @DaveA WebSecurity.Login calls FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie. This is standard asp.net form auth stuff.

Comment: @zespri, I haven't used this method, but I should've known. missed the persistant cookies part.

Comment: @AspAsp do you have any particular reason for using session? user name is available from the context (`User.Identity.Name`)

Comment: @zespri, clearly I'm missing something. I see the condition **if (ModelState.IsValid && WebSecurity.Login(model.UserName, model.Password, persistCookie: model.RememberMe))**, but not an actual login that persists...

Comment: @zespri thank you, I can't user that context alone, as in page redirection the User is null

Comment: @AspAsp what do you mean?

Comment: @zespri I think I asked about this User once (using another SO account) that my login needs to check if the login user is an administrator or just a normal user, each of who is redirected toa  different layout. Using User to check before page redirection is invalid as it is not yet initialized (only after the page is fully redirected.)

Comment: @AspAsp I'm not sure what you mean. Page redirection is not somethinng that gets initialized, so saying that "page redirection is invalid as it is not yet initialized" does not make sense to me. In your controller actions you always have access to the current user principal/identity if you are logged in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must *always* be prepared for session state to be cleared. For instance, if the web.config file is changed, the worker process will be recycled and all in-process session state will be lost. You can mitigate that by using out of process session state, but still, as a best practice, you should be prepared to lose your session at any time.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to check whether you are logged in or not as your cookie is persisted . It has noting to do with the sessions because session will never exist after you close the browser unless you were storing session in DB or state

Answer (score 0):

As the Previous replies state you cannot reply on sessionstate to still be valid after the browser has closed.
The following two articles should help

[ASP.NET Session State Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581.aspx)

[ASP.NET State Management Recommendations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z1hkazw7.aspx)

Tim